# MySql - Select between date together with other datatype

Tags: mysql

I want to select varchar within date. I already tried code below but it will ignore date selection. It will select outside(and inside) the date range.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM register
    WHERE company LIKE '%abc%' OR address LIKE '%def%'
    AND Timestamp
    BETWEEN  '2011-8-1 10:00:00'
    AND  '2011-8-31 10:00:00'
```

If I just leave the date itself, yes it works

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM register
    WHERE Timestamp
    BETWEEN  '2011-8-1 10:00:00'
    AND  '2011-8-31 10:00:00'
```

I just want select varchar WITHIN selected date. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of operators `OR` and `AND` precendence.

Wrap your whole `OR` part with parenthesis

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM register
    WHERE (company LIKE '%abc%' OR address LIKE '%def%')
    AND Timestamp
    BETWEEN  '2011-8-1 10:00:00'
    AND  '2011-8-31 10:00:00'
```